# Net Core: Write Unit Test Case for Slideshow Carousel

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

I created a Bootstrap Slideshow and several card components. How would I even begin testing that the slideshow works with Xunit? I need to ensure that the slider, left right arrows actually work, that they render the same picture, that the captions show. I added some custom code. How would I write a webtest to ensure that slide arrows work for example?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

```css
.imgcarousel {
    width:100%;
}


.carouselleftarrow {
    font-family: Material Icons;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    content: "\e408";
}

.carouselrightarrow {
    font-family: Material Icons;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    content: "\e409";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
   rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="Carouselid0efe5f93f1734c5a967cf4ff7c47775a" style="  width: 500px;
   height: 500px;">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#Carouselid0efe5f93f1734c5a967cf4ff7c47775a" class=""></li>
      <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#Carouselid0efe5f93f1734c5a967cf4ff7c47775a" class=""></li>
      <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#Carouselid0efe5f93f1734c5a967cf4ff7c47775a" class="active"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7"></div>
      <div class="item active"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://www.mcpl.us/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/bookstack.jpg?itok=pHICdzg9"></div>
   </div>
   <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#Carouselid0efe5f93f1734c5a967cf4ff7c47775a"><span class="carouselleftarrow">navigate_before</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#Carouselid0efe5f93f1734c5a967cf4ff7c47775a"><span class="carouselrightarrow">navigate_next</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
public class MyTests
{
    private IWebDriver _webdriver = new ChromeDriver();

    [Fact]
    public void CarouselWithMultipleItems_ClickRightButton_NavigatesToNextItem()
    {
        // Arrange
        // Load page
        _webdriver.Url = "your-url-here";

        // Wait until right button is clickable
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
        WebElement rightArrow = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a.right.carousel-control")));

        // Act
        rightArrow.Click();

        // Assert
        WebElement caption = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("<caption-selector-here>")));
        // You might need another wait here
        WebElement picture = _webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".imgcarousel.active"));

        // Do your assert logic here
    }
}
```

Should get you started. It goes without saying that you will need to include the relevant xUnit NuGet pacakges
along with the Selenium.WebDriver, Selenium.Support, SeleniumChrome.WebDriver, and DotNetSeleniumExtras (there might be some other required ones too).